# How to copy files to given named usb stick with cmd?

Tags: cmd.exe

I want to copy c:\test\myphoto.jpg to F: if the name of F: disk is "Rejepow" from cmd.

How can I do it?

If it is impossible from cmd could you explain how to do it on c++?

From comment by OP:

I have tried it by removing `@echo off`, also I have changed `If[%%d]==[F:] to If[%%d]==[G:]`.

Output of `wmic logicaldisk get caption, volumename` is:

```
C: 
D: 
E: 
G: REJEPOW
```

Comment: You shouldn't just say "didn't work". You should update your question showing a copy/paste from the command line proving what didn't work. Also bear in mind that since your english is very poor, you should make all the more effort to provide copy/pastes from the command line to show exactly what is going on

Comment: @barlop Ok!I didn't try last answer.I will try it but barlop can you answer my this qyestion? http://superuser.com/questions/1138021/how-to-detect-truecrypt-drive-or-usb-stick-with-cmd

Comment: I don't have a usb stick on me so my tests are limited also, it looks like your last question is dependent on this one. So try to get david postil's answer here to work for you , and then try to apply it(david postil's solution to this), to your problem there. So after you get the answer to this,then try to apply it to the other one and edit the other one with your attempt and any error. Your other question might even be solved by the answer to this.And notice this was a good question it even got an upvote, unlike your other attempt at a question. As this question gets to the core of the issue

Comment: And this question highlights what somebody writing a batch file might actually struggle with.. And this question is useful to others as it is not too specific to your problem, and others could potentially use it. You should've given your disk an easier name though to make it even clearer but doesn't matter now.

Comment: -1 your question loses value because your last comments suggested that for some reason answer you accepted didn't work for you, we don't know why,  or what if anything you did to make it work, it looks like you didn't even try to make it work, you tried your own answer but accepted the other. Tests were suggested to you that'd try to get the answer you accepted to work for you and you ignored them and accepted an answer that (going by your comments) wasn't working for you. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to copy c:\test\myphoto.jpg to F: if the name of F: disk is "Rejepow"

**Solution 1:**

Use the following batch file (CopyToRejepow.cmd).

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, volumename ^| findstr -i "Rejepow"') do (
  copy c:\test\myphoto.jpg %%d
  )
endlocal
```

**Solution 2:**

Use the following command line.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, volumename ^| findstr -i "Rejepow"') do copy c:\test\myphoto.jpg %d
```

Notes:

- Your question specifies explicitly to copy only if it is drive F:.
- Assuming that it is a mistake I have modified the answer to copy the file to every disk labelled REJEPOW (which is not the spelling you gave in your question).

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) - Copy one or more files to another location.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: Nope,it didn't work.

Comment: @K.Rejepow Remove the `echo off`, run it again and include the output

Comment: @K.Rejepow Also run `wmic logicaldisk get caption, volumename` and include the output of that. Please [edit] you question to include the results.

Comment: I have tried removing @echo off but it didn't work.Output of wmic logicaldisk get caption, volumename is:C: D: E: G:     REJEPOW

Comment: Your question specifies explicitly to copy only if it is drive F:. Assuming that it is a mistake I have modified the answer to copy the file to every disk labelled REJEPOW (which is not the spelling you gave in your question).

Comment: I have also tried by changing if[%%d]==[F:] to if[%%d]==[G:] but it didn't work also.

Comment: Ok I have also changed "Rejepow" to "REJEPOW" in batch file.

Comment: @K.Rejepow That should work. Or see my modified answer.

Comment: @K.Rejepow Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept it](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: It is also didn't work.I have changed "Rejepow" to "REJEPOW" but myphoto.jpg didn't copy to G:.I have tryed this codes one by one but when I eneter "for /f "tokens=1,2" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, volumename ^| findstr -i "Rejepow"')" it gives:%%d was unexpected at this time" error.What can I do else?

Comment: @K.Rejepow You need to create a batch file exactly as in the answer and run that. If that doesn't work I don't know what is wrong. I have tested it here. I've also added a command line version to the answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill You wrote "You need to create a batch file exactly as in the answer and run that. If that doesn't work I don't know what is wrong" <-- You could walk him through some troubleshooting e.g. ask him to run that `'wmic logicaldisk.........'` line mention what output he should get(so we/techies present and future,+ideally he, can all follow along too), and then you observe/verify if it's the expected output e.t.c. and other elements of the batch like the conditionals in there. finding the problem.  I'd help out myself if I had a usb stick around

Comment: @barlop We already did that (read the rest of the comments). The output is in the question ... and I've tested it here (exactly as the OP specified). It works.

Comment: @barlop My guess is he's trying to run the batch file command from the command line, so I provided a command line version as well. No response from the OP since than.

Comment: @K.Rejepow  here is an example of pasting output from cmd prompt, so include the whole prompt http://pastebin.com/raw/hrxpe5Sv    And when I try it then as davidpostil suggested,  if you run the command with %%d at the command like, then you get that error that the %%d was unexpected. But the command with %%d works for me if it's in a batch file. There are ways to troubleshoot further if u still have errors. (@david such as simplifying what's in the for header and seeing if he still gets the error, or even doing xxd -p viewing the bytes of the chars, and checking that the for header is right)!

Comment: @K.Rejepow so try to do the commands that I showed in my pastebin link, and if you get a different result that amounts to not working, then copy/paste the output into your question, and you could make a pastebin link too, and we can compare output.. so you can prove whether if for example, you run exactly what I did, you get the error even for the bat file. So you need to rely less on your english, and even on your accuracy, and simply rely on a copy/paste of the cmd console to make your points.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok guys.Thanks all of you!At last I could make an .exe program that does my work;)I will write how did I made that;)

Comment: @K.Rejepow can you also try to get it working as a batch file. Notice that from the cmd window you use %d but from batch file you use %%d.  Look at my pastebin link and see if you can reproduce it. It'd be much better if you can solve it not just from the c+++batch way but from the pure batch file way.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your batch code but it didn't work,although your command line answer was true and guess what I did;)I wrote a c++ program which runs your command line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main() {
system("for /f \"tokens=1,2\" %d in (\'wmic logicaldisk get caption^, volumename ^| findstr -i \"Rejepow\" \') do copy c:\\test\\myphoto.jpg %d);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have to test the solution yourself, then accept it when you know it works,  dave postil's solution should work but you should do the test suggested to you

Comment: @K.Rejepow That batch file is **the exact equivalent** of the command line.

Comment: @DavidPostill but it didn't work.Maybe my antivirus blocks it.But c++ program worked.But also I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @barlop can you answer my this question: http://superuser.com/questions/1138021/how-to-detect-truecrypt-drive-or-usb-stick-of-given-drive-with-cmd?noredirect=1#

Comment: @DavidPostill can you too please?: http://superuser.com/questions/1138021/how-to-detect-truecrypt-drive-or-usb-stick-of-given-drive-with-cmd?noredirect=1#

Comment: @K.Rejepow <shrug> Thanks for the acceptance :)