# How to detect truecrypt drive or usb stick of given drive with cmd?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe, truecrypt

I wanted to copy F:*.docx to C: if F:drive is truecrypt's drive.

If it is a USB stick don't copy it.

The difference between truecrypt's F: drive and usb stick's is one of them is not removable and "diskpart" can not detect it.

I mean if F: drive is not removable copy all docx files, if it is removable don't copy anything.

Can this be done in batch script?

Comment: This is the 3rd question where you have asked for a script. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Oh sorry David.But I don't know a lot of thing about cmd.exe.

Comment: Then it's time for you to start learning.

Comment: C++ (programming) is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I detect a USB stick (removable drive)?

> If F: drive is not removable copy all docx files if it is removable don't copy anything

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption^, drivetype') do (
  rem look for drive f:
  if [%%d] EQU [F:] (
    rem look for non removable drive
    rem drivetype 2 is removable
    if [%%e] NEQ [2] (
      echo copy files
      )
    )
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Replace `echo copy files` with an appropriate command.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) - Copy one or more files to another location.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.

Comment: @DaveThank Dave.I didn't try it yet but I will, today.Also can you give me command line code pleasee:)

Comment: Put the `for` and `if`s all on one line. Replace `%%` with `%`

Comment: Oh soory it shouldn't be Dave.

Comment: Dave;/I have tried that command but it didn't work also;(.I have tried every method,but I couldn't do my claim for days!Is there any alternative method?

Comment: @K.Rejepow There is clearly something strange about your PC. I have tested the scripts for all 3 of your questions and they work for me.

Comment: I forgot something to say,diskpart can't detect Truecrypt drive and doesn't show when I call "list volume" what can I do else?

Comment: What does `diskpart` have to do with anything? It's not mentioned in your question. If you have a question about `diskpart` and `truecrypt` then please ask a new question.

Comment: ;(I don't ask diskpart,just I need to copy Truecrypts drive's files,your last batch script didn't work.I thought it doesn't work because of F: is not looking as any volume.Can we say to cmd copy F:\*.docx if F:is not volume?Pleaseee help I need it.

Comment: @DavidPostillI have tested it on .bat and on .cmd,also on command line 3 of them didn't work:(

Comment: You will have to figure it out yourself. I don't use truecrypt.

Comment: It sounds like your truecrypt is broken. Please ask a new question about that.